# Mongo client does not receive responce from Mongo server for long-running operation

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to aggregate large collection and save result in temp collection. This operation on server(js) requires about 20 min.

I using on client different approaches aggregation framework with out statement or cursors to receive result or calling stored procedure using eval.

My requests are processed by server: temp collection is created, but response from it is not received and my code is stuck.

Timeout for Socket is initialized by default

My code using aggregation framework

```
var res =
                collection.Aggregate(new AggregateOptions {AllowDiskUse = true})
                    .Match(
                        new BsonDocumentFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {"EventId", 360},
                            {"EventDate", new BsonDocument("$gte", date)}
                        }))
                    .Project(new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {"_id", 0},
                        {"license", "$Payload.licenseId"},
                        {"device", "$Payload.deviceId"},
                        {
                            "date",
                            new BsonDocument("$dateToString",
                                new BsonDocument {{"format", "%Y-%m-%d"}, {"date", "$EventDate"}})
                        },
                        {"EventDate", 1}
                    })
                    .Group(new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {"_id", new BsonDocument {{"license", "$license"}, {"date", "$date"}}},
                        {"device", new BsonDocument("$first", "$device")},
                        {"license", new BsonDocument("$first", "$license")},
                        {"eventDateFirst", new BsonDocument("$min", "$EventDate")},
                        {"eventDateLast", new BsonDocument("$max", "$EventDate")},
                        {"activity", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1)}
                    }).OutAsync("licenseActivity8").Result;
```

And by stored procedure:

```
var bv = db.Eval("aggregateUserActions360");
            db.Eval(new EvalArgs
            {
                Lock = false,
                Code = bv.AsBsonJavaScript.Code,
                Args = new BsonValue[] { new DateTime(2015, 10, 1), "licenseActivity7" }
            });
```

I saw the same error https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/FyMIR_Wf5s0

Any ideas?